# the router doesn't select correct function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

When I use `postman` to login a user with `http://localhost:3000/login` but it always run the register function. Code runs ok, it just routes to wrong function. How to redirect it to `login` when the url is login and vice-versa. Both the login and register functions are in the same `authentication.js` file.

**controllers/authentication.js**

```
exports.register = (req, res) => {

[Some long code here]

 });


exports.login = (req, res, next) => { 

[Some long code here]

 });
```

**routes/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const ctrlAuth = require("../../controllers/authentication");
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', ctrlAuth.register);
router.post('/', ctrlAuth.login);

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const userRoutes = require("./app_api/routes/index");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/login", userRoutes);
app.use("/register", userRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason here is everytime a route starting with login or register hits your express server it is routed to userRoutes file as both **login** and **register** path segment use same routing file as per your code.

```
app.use("/login", userRoutes);  // ---> pointing to userRoutes
app.use("/register", userRoutes); // ---> pointing to userRoutes
```

Once express moves to userRoutes the path segment left to match is "/" and method type POST. And the first route satisfies both the condition. Hence API call always end up being served by the register handler.

```
// match found here for "/" segment and post method type
router.post('/', ctrlAuth.register); 

// --> this route is never reached
router.post('/', ctrlAuth.login);
```

**ANSWER**

To overcome this problem you can make these changes in your files.

**app.js**

*Remove these lines:*

```
app.use("/login", userRoutes);
app.use("/register", userRoutes);
```

*Replace With:*

```
app.use("", userRoutes);
```

**routes/index.js**

*Remove these lines:*

```
router.post('/', ctrlAuth.register);
router.post('/', ctrlAuth.login);
```

*Replace With:*

```
router.post('/register', ctrlAuth.register);
router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login);
```